# Zeros of the derivative of Riemann's $\xi$-function

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

The Riemann xi function $\xi(s)$ is defined as
$$
\xi(s)=\frac12 s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s).
$$
It is an entire function whose zeros are precisely those of $\zeta(s)$.
Since $\xi$ is real valued on the critical line $s=1/2+it$, there is a zero of the derivative $\xi^\prime$ between each successive pair of zeros of $\xi$, and thus the theorem of Levinson  shows that at least $1/3$ (since improved) of the zeros of $\xi^\prime$ lie on the critical line.

In *Zeros of the derivative of Riemann's $\xi$-function*  BAMS v. 80 (5) 1974 pp. 951-954, Levinson adapted his method to show directly that more than $7/10$ of the zeros of $\xi^\prime(s)$ occur on the critical line.  In the proof he writes, (with $H(s)=\frac12 s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)$, $F(s)$ defined by $H(s)=\exp(F(s))$, and $G(s)$ complicated in terms of $\zeta(s)$ and $\zeta^\prime(s)$)

> "… then (3) becomes $$
>  \xi^\prime(s)=F^\prime(s)H(s)G(s)-F^\prime(1-s)H(1-s)G(1-s) $$ 
>   … by
>   Stirling's formula $\arg H(1/2+it)$ changes rapidly and by itself
>   would supply the full quota of zeros of $\xi^\prime(s)$ on
>   $\sigma=1/2$."

This is as close as he comes in the paper to suggesting that all the zeros of $\xi^\prime$ are on the critical line.

---

Does this conjecture explicitly appear anywhere in the literature?  Is it folklore?

Comment: I think you intended to write "7/10 of the zeros of the _derivative_"...?

Comment: A proof that, on RH, $\xi'(s)=0 \implies \mathrm{Re}(s)=1/2$ is outlined in exercise 1 on page 443 of Montgomery & Vaughan's "Multiplicative Number Theory."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In exercise 1 on page 443 of their book "Multiplicative Number Theory," Montgomery & Vaughan outline a proof of the statement:

"Assuming the Riemann Hypothesis, $\xi'(s)=0 \implies \mathrm{Re}(s)=1/2$."

Assuming RH, let $s=\sigma+it$ and let $\rho=\frac{1}{2}+i\gamma$ denote a zero of $\xi(s)$. The main idea of their argument is that, on RH, it follows from that Hadamard product for $\xi(s)$ that
$$ \mathrm{Re} \frac{\xi'}{\xi}(s) = \sum_{\rho} \mathrm{Re}\frac{1}{s-\rho} = \sum_\gamma \frac{\sigma-1/2}{(\sigma-1/2)^2+(t-\gamma)^2}.$$
Now if $\xi'(s)=0$, then the left-hand side of the above expression is zero. On the other hand, the only way that the sum over $\gamma$ vanishes is if $\sigma=1/2$, i.e. $\mathrm{Re}(s)=1/2$.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if this argument was not known to Levinson as it is similar to Levinson & Montgomery's proof of Speiser's Theorem: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02392141

Comment: Note This is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem adapted to an entire function with appropriate order and all its roots on some strip or some line.

Comment: And hence : $\xi(s)$ has no zeros on $Re(s) > 1/2+\epsilon$ (and $Re(s) < 1/2-\sigma_0$) $\implies$ that $\xi'(s)$ has no zeros on $Re(s) > 1/2+\epsilon$ and $Re(s) < 1/2-\epsilon$

Answer (score 12):

The Riemann hypothesis implies that the zeros of derivatives of all orders of $\xi$ lie on the critical line.

> B. Conrey, Zeros of derivatives of Riemann’s xi-function on the critical line, J. Number Theory 16 (1983), 49-74.

Comment: Conrey says "It can be shown that..." but does not prove it or cite a reference.  Is it folklore?

Answer (score 8):

The Riemann hypothesis implies that the function $\Xi(z)=\xi(1/2+iz)$ is in the 
Laguerre-Pólya class. Therefore it is a limit, uniformly on compact sets, of a
sequence of polynomials with real roots.  The derivatives are also again in the same
class and have therefore only real zeros. It follows that all zeros of $\xi(s)$ and its derivatives will be on the critical line.

I imagine that this is due to Pólya, but have not his Collected Works to confirm.

Given the simplicity of the proof I noticed, I will give a sketch of it. 
We have
$$\Xi(t)=\Xi(0)\prod_{n=1}^\infty \Bigl(1-\frac{t^2}{\alpha_n^2}\Bigr).$$
The Riemann hypothesis is that all $\alpha_n$ are real.

Therefore, assuming RH, $\Xi(t)$ is  the limit uniformly in compact sets of $\bf C$ of the polynomials 
$$P_N(t):=\Xi(0)\prod_{n=1}^N \Bigl(1-\frac{t^2}{\alpha_n^2}\Bigr).$$
We are assuming that all roots of these polynomials are real.  Therefore the same will happen with 
any derivative $P_N^{(k)}(t)$.

By the general Theorems of Complex Analysis $\lim_{N\to\infty}P_N^{(k)}(t)=\Xi^{(k)}(t)$ uniformly in compact sets. 
By the argument principle any zero of $\Xi^{(k)}(t)$ is limit of zeros of $P_N^{(k)}(t)$. Therefore
any zero of $\Xi^{(k)}(t)$ is real.  The relation  $\Xi(t)=\xi(\frac12+it)$ implies that all the zeros of the derivatives of
$\xi(s)$ are in the critical line.

(It is essentially contained in the paper by G. Pólya,  Bemerkung zur Theorie der ganzen Funktionen, Collected papers II, 154--162.)

Answer (score 4):

The same argument as in the [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem#Proof) (adapted to an entire function with appropriate order) works for showing that

> If $\xi(1/2+s)$ has no zeros on $|Re(s)| > \alpha$,
>
> then $\xi'(1/2+s)$ has no zeros on $|Re(s)| > \alpha$.

grouping the term $\rho$ with its complex conjugate $\overline{\rho}$,

$\displaystyle \frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)} = \sum_\rho \frac{1}{s-\rho}$ converges conditionally so that

$$\begin{array}{l}\displaystyle\ \ \ \ \xi'(\beta)=0 \\ \displaystyle\text{and }\xi(\beta)\ne 0\end{array}\implies  \frac{\xi'(\beta)}{\xi(\beta)} = \sum_\rho \frac{\overline{\beta}-\overline{\rho}}{|\beta-\rho|^2}=0\quad\implies \quad\beta=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_\rho \frac{\rho}{|\beta-\rho|^2}}{\displaystyle\sum_{\rho}\frac{1}{|\beta-\rho|^2}}$$
which is a weighted sum of the zeros of $\xi(s)$, i.e. the zeros of $\xi'(s)$ lie in the convex hull of the zeros of $\xi(s)$.

---

Now for $\zeta(s)$ it is different, the zeros of $\zeta'(s)$ are not in the convex hull of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, since $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$ and the trivial zeros sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{s+2n}$ diverges.

See [*zeros of $\zeta'(s)$ and the Riemann hypothesis*](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256052045) for a proof that under the RH $\zeta'(s)$ has no zeros on $Re(0,1/2)$.  I'd like if someone could derive a similar theorem assuming instead that $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros on $Re(s) > \sigma_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Related proof is in [Lagarias paper p.1](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa89/aa8932.pdf).

The RH is equivalent to

$$
\Re\left(\frac{\xi'(s)}{\xi(s)}\right) > 0
$$

When $\Re(s) > \frac12$.

Comment: It is not proven in that paper, but rather Lagarias cites Hinkkanen that the above is true.  From this it follows that RH $\Rightarrow$ the zeros of $\xi^\prime$ lie on the critical line.

Comment: @Stopple Agreed. Though I believe some results from the paper are stronger and show the same.