# Are the zeros of $\zeta'$ exactly the zeros of $\zeta$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

The Riemann Hypothesis is known to be equivalent to the statement that $\zeta'$ (the derivative of the Riemann zeta function) has no zeros in the region $0< \Re(s) < 1/2$. By the functional equation, this seems to be equivalent to saying that the zeros of $\zeta'$ are actually on the critical line $\Re(s) = 1/2$. Also, it is known that the truth of the RH implies that all the zeros of the integer derivatives of $\xi(s)$ - the Riemann xi function, are also on the critical line.

So my question is: Are the zeros of $\zeta'$ exactly the zeros of $\zeta$, which the above seems to suggest ?

Comment: And [see there](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/190802/zeros-of-the-derivative-of-riemanns-xi-function/255198#255198) for a simple argument showing why the RH implies that all the derivatives of $\xi(s)$ have their zeros on the critical line (of course most of the zeros are simple, and are between two zeros of the anti-derivative)

Answer (score 5):

No.  All known zeros of $\zeta$ are of order $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, the Riemann Hypothesis (in the stronger version which says all the zeros are simple) implies that all zeros of $\zeta^\prime(s)$ have real part $> 1/2$.  This is proved in "Zeros of the derivatives of the Riemann zeta function", by Levinson and Montgomery.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\geq 1/2$? AFAIK RH doesn't imply zeta zeros are simple, which would be a conclusion of your statement.

Comment: The stronger version of RH *includes* the simplicity of the zeros.