# Zeros of the derivative of $\xi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

In his paper on [Zeros of derivatives of Riemann $\xi$-function on critical line](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-314X(83)90031-8) Brian Conrey mention that

> It can be shown that the Riemann hypothesis implies that all zeros of $\xi (s)$, the derivative of $\xi$-function, have real part $1/2$ for any $m$. Where
> $$\xi(s)=\frac{1}{2}s(s-1)\pi^{-s/2}\Gamma\bigg(\frac{s}{2}\bigg) \zeta(s).$$

Could anyone kindly recommend some references, books, or scholarly articles that elaborate on this topic? I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Thank you in anticipation!

Comment: See the answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190802/zeros-of-the-derivative-of-riemanns-xi-function?rq=1

Comment: In addition to the answers given, I'll note that I think of this as following from the fact that if $f(z)$ is a polynomial, then the roots of $f'(z)$ lie within the convex hull of the roots of $f(z)$. RH implies that $\xi(s)$ is sufficiently well-approximated by complex polynomials for this argument to carry through.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I discuss these ideas here:  https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15608

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the Riemann hypothesis, the $\xi(1/2+iz)$-function belongs to the Laguerre-Polya class (defined as the closure of polynomials with all zeros real). This follows from the parametric description of this class obtained by Laguerre and Polya: it consists exactly of the functions of the form
$$cz^me^{-az^2+bz}\prod\left(1-\frac{z}{a_k}\right)e^{z/a_k},$$
where $a\leq 0,$ $b$ and $a_k$ are real. Since Riemann $\zeta$ and $\xi$ have order $1$, Hadamard's factorization implies that $\zeta(1/2+iz)$ has this form (assuming that all $a_k$ are real), thus it belongs to the Laguerre-Polya class,
and then it evident from the definition this class, that all zeros of all derivatives are also real.